# How to keep CouchDB efficiently with a lot of DELETE, purge?

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb database with ~2000 documents (50MB), but 150K deleted documents in 3 months, and will be increase.

So, What is the better strategy to keep the performance high? 
Use purge + compact, periodically re-create entire database?

The couchdb documentation recommends re-create database when store short-term data, isn't my case but the delete is constant in some kind of documents.

[DELETE operation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/performance.html#delete-operation)

> If your use case creates lots of deleted documents (for example, if you are storing short-term data like log entries, message queues, etc), you might want to periodically switch to a new database and delete the old one (once the entries in it have all expired).

Using `Apache CouchDB v. 2.1.1`

Comment: Is performance a problem for you? 2000 document seems so small that I would imagine performance should be blazing fast still.

Comment: No, that's no problem for now, but I need design a solution before become a problem, the system is 24x7, and my budget is limited. More resources (space, process or memory) could be a problem. Purge + compact will be cleaning the data from disk?

Comment: You should use compaction before purging. After compaction, a very little footprint of the deleted document are kept(for replication purpose). Usually, CouchDB will autocompact when disk reach a certain threshold

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy about that, but I'm not think this like YAGNI and Big Design Up Front principles, just better strategy to let environment healthy. Putting the trail when the train arrive :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexisCôté I will configure the Replication + Compaction + Purge as you suggested and post the results.

Comment: I meant that you should let CouchDB autocompact the database if it grows. You can always change the compaction threshold if you want to lower your database size. Otherwise, I won't force compactions or purge.

Comment: Compaction helps with the database size but it will not help if you use filtered replications. In that case, document thombstones will be included during database filtering and could drive you into a performance problem if the database grows in terms of number of documents. If you have filters it is advisable to use one of the approaches you propose.

Answer (score 0):

The purge operation is not implemented at cluster level in CouchDB 2.x series (from 2.0.0 to 2.2.0) so it doesn't seem to be an option in your case.

This seems that will be supported in the next release 2.3.0. You can check the related issue [here](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1378).

The same issue includes a possible workaround based on a database switch approach described [here](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2015/04/20/how-to-finally-delete-documents-in-couchdb/).

In your case, with Apache CouchDB 2.1.1 database switch is the only viable option.

Comment: Now with 2.3.0 being released, you are able to purge documents. You must send an api-call for every single document to be purged, providing doc-id plus even rev-ids. 
By now, there is no "purge all deleted" in 2.3.0.
CouchDB synced docs in other databases must be purged as well.